# Signing PDF with PDFBox and BouncyCastle

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to sign a PDF using PDFBox, and it does sign but when  I open the document in adobe reader I get the following message "Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed" can someone please help me find the problem.

The keystore was created with "keytool -genkeypair -storepass 123456 -storetype pkcs12 -alias test -validity 365 -v -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.p12"

Using pdfbox-1.8.9 and bcpkix-jdk15on-1.52

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.SignatureException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.PDSignature;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.SignatureInterface;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaCertStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class CreateSignature implements SignatureInterface {
    private static PrivateKey privateKey;
    private static Certificate certificate;

    boolean signPdf(File pdfFile, File signedPdfFile) {

        try (
                FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedPdfFile);
                PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)) {
            int readCount;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            while ((readCount = fis1.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            }

            PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
            signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
            signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
            signature.setName("NAME");
            signature.setLocation("LOCATION");
            signature.setReason("REASON");
            signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            doc.addSignature(signature, this);
            doc.saveIncremental(fis, fos);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream is) throws SignatureException, IOException {
        try {
            BouncyCastleProvider BC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(Collections.singletonList(certificate));

            CMSTypedDataInputStream input = new CMSTypedDataInputStream(is);
            CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            ContentSigner sha512Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSA").setProvider(BC).build(privateKey);

            gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                    new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(BC).build()).build(sha512Signer, new X509CertificateHolder(certificate.getEncoded())
            ));
            gen.addCertificates(certStore);
            CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(input, false);

            return signedData.getEncoded();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, SignatureException, COSVisitorException {
        char[] password = "123456".toCharArray();

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("/home/user/Desktop/keystore.p12"), password);

        Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();
        String alias;
        if (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = aliases.nextElement();
        } else {
            throw new KeyStoreException("Keystore is empty");
        }
        privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, password);
        Certificate[] certificateChain = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        certificate = certificateChain[0];

        File inFile = new File("/home/user/Desktop/sign.pdf");
        File outFile = new File("/home/user/Desktop/sign_signed.pdf");
        new CreateSignature().signPdf(inFile, outFile);
    }
}


class CMSTypedDataInputStream implements CMSTypedData {
    InputStream in;

    public CMSTypedDataInputStream(InputStream is) {
        in = is;
    }

    @Override
    public ASN1ObjectIdentifier getContentType() {
        return PKCSObjectIdentifiers.data;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getContent() {
        return in;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException,
            CMSException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Fixing "Document has been altered or corrupted"

The mistake is that you call `PDDocument.saveIncremental` with an `InputStream` merely covering the original PDF:

```
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedPdfFile);
...
doc.saveIncremental(fis, fos);
```

But the method expects the `InputStream` to cover the original file plus the changes made to prepare for signing.

Thus, `fis` also needs to point to `signedPdfFile`, and as that file might not exist before, the order of creating `fis` and `fos` must be switched>

```
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedPdfFile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(signedPdfFile);
...
doc.saveIncremental(fis, fos);
```

Unfortunately the JavaDocs don't Point this out.

### Another issue

There is another issue with the generated signature. If you look at the ASN.1 dump of a sample result, you'll see something starting like this:

```
    <30 80>
   0 NDEF: SEQUENCE {
    <06 09>
   2    9:   OBJECT IDENTIFIER signedData (1 2 840 113549 1 7 2)
         :     (PKCS #7)
    <A0 80>
  13 NDEF:   [0] {
    <30 80>
  15 NDEF:     SEQUENCE {
    <02 01>
  17    1:       INTEGER 1
    <31 0F>
  20   15:       SET {
```

The `NDEF` length indications show that the *indefinite-length method* is used for encoding these outer layers of the signature container. Use of this method is allowed in the *Basic Encoding Rules (BER)* but not in the more strict *Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER)*. While using BER for the outer layers is allowed for generic PKCS#7/CMS signatures, the PDF specification clearly requires:

> When PKCS#7 signatures are used, the value of **Contents** shall be a DER-encoded PKCS#7 binary data object containing the signature.
>
> *(section 12.8.3.3.1 "PKCS#7 Signatures as used in ISO 32000" / "General" in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Thus, **strictly speaking your signature is even structurally invalid**. Usually, though, this is not detected by PDF signature verification services because most of them use standard PKCS#7/CMS libraries or methods for verifying the signature containers.

If you want to make sure that your signatures are truly valid PDF signatures, you can achieve this by replacing

```
return signedData.getEncoded();
```

by something like

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DEROutputStream dos = new DEROutputStream(baos);
dos.writeObject(signedData.toASN1Structure());
return baos.toByteArray();
```

Now the whole signature object is DER-encoded.

*(You can find a test creating signatures both with your original and the fixed code either with or without improved encoding here: [SignLikeLoneWolf.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/sign/SignLikeLoneWolf.java))*

Comment: So very helpful!

Comment: can I generate PDF with visible Digital sign using the same above code?

Comment: The question is more than five years old. You should instead base new signing code on the current versions of the PDFBox examples `CreateVisibleSignature` and `CreateVisibleSignature2`.